# Force on a test charge inside a cell

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, batteries, electrochemistry, ions

Considering test charge inside a cell. Let the cell be in an ***open circuit***. I know that a potential difference will develop between the two electrodes of the cell. If I take a test charge and place it in the centre will it experience any force. Please consider that I am using a test charge and the charge is not being generated by the electrochemical reactions that take place inside the cell.

As far as I know one of the electrode wants to give electrons to the solution while one of the electrode wants to take electrons from the solution. This causes a difference of charges between the two electrodes which causes the potential difference to develop.

//.......

MY THEORY-(NOT FROM  A SOURCE)
I think that this potential difference generates a field and the electrochemical reaction continues and potential diff. keeps increasing until they attain an equilibrium with each other, and the field no longer allows the electrons to flow between electrodes and the solution.

//..............

My source states that a test charge placed inside the solution feels no force at all while I think that this is true only for electrons because they have a tendency to get into or away from the metal electrode while the developed field due to the potential difference of opposes this tendency.so a test charges placed by us will feel some force due to the field inside the cell.

please tell if the section in MY THEORY is true.And whether a test charge placed inside a cell in an ***open circuit*** feels no force?

Comment: I think the reason you aren't getting traction is because you seem to use words differently from the rest of us. A test charge (ok) in a cell (?). Please specify: between parallel plates? Inside a grounded box? We can't tell what you are describing.

Comment: A test charge placed in between the electrodes of a galvanic cell.

Comment: The cell is not connected to any external circuit.does the test charge move in the cell even though there is no external wire connection.

Comment: The question came in a test.i am specifying all information that was made available to me.sorry but I do not have any thing further which I could add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The potential difference caused by the open state electrodes is cancelled by the ion charge net offset, so the macroscale potential gradient is zero. Otherwise, there would be ion electromigration until it is zero again.

If you put a (smal enough) test charge there, there would be just local interation with neighbor ion charges, or with itself, if it is not a point charge.

---

In other words, you asked this:

> *If I had a Petri dish half filled by water and if I tilted it slightly, would the water stay tilted as the dish would be? If I laid there a small piece of wood, would it flow downhill?*

The answer is obvious:

No, water(ions) realigns to keep the water level horizontal (zero electrostatic gradient), so the wood(test charge) will not move anywhere (unless for other reasons).

Comment: so no net electric field exists inside the cell in an open state

Comment: @manjitsingh  In other words, you ask this: *If I had a Petri dish half filled by water and if I tilted it slightly, would the water stay tilted as the dish would be, so I could lay there a piece of wood which would flow downhill?*

Comment: damn thats a good analogy.i wish i could give you some bounty or something because that is elegant.it would be nice if you edit it into the official answer.

Comment: Thanks and done. :-)